# What are some good interview questions for a potential Flex developer?

Tags: apache-flex

I plan on interviewing Flex candidates in the near future and I'm looking for some good (read: not incredibly difficult) Flex development questions.

Any input from the Stackoverflow community?  If you post a possible question, the answer is also appreciated (but not required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Explain the UIComponent lifecycle, including important methods like initialize(), createChildren(), etc.
2. Explain the invalidation model and how it works for properties, measuring and the display list.
3. Name three different ways to achieve data binding
4. Explain the event model in Flash. Describe how bubbling events works. Explain what a weak-referenced event listener is and why you'd use it.
5. Describe what the IResponder interface consists of and how it is used.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic:**

- MXML vis-a-vis AS overview
- Flex/AIR difference
- Build process (projects, resources)
- Basic type handling, functions
- Event Handling
- Standard UI Components

**Medium:**

- Custom UI Components
- WebServices/HTTPRequest
- External Interface
- Dynamic classes, reflection etc
- Optimization
- Some knowledge of Flash player security

**Advanced:**

- Shared modules, Local Communication
- AS3 Type System details
- Garbage Collection
- Flash player security, sandboxes, crossdomain.xml
- Installation/Update of AIR apps

**Specialized:**

- LCDS/Blaze integration
- PHP/JS interoperability
- AMF

My $0.02. You are free to rearrange. This is just a **subjective** viewpoint, please let me know why you're down modding?

Comment: These really aren't questions.  They're guidelines to the types of questions to ask.  Still valuable, but doesn't address the root question.

Comment: If you are asking us to provide questions, you're defeating your own purpose. Who knows, if the potential candidate is not reading SO at this instant? Cheers :)

Comment: Hmm...what's it say that I know some things from all of those categories, but also haven't touched some of the things in most of them? :)

Comment: @Herms: You're not applying, are you? Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ask them what MVC architectures they are familiar with (EasyMVC, Cairngorm, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Jesse Warden, a prominent Flex developer, recently posted a decent list of [Flex interview questions](http://jesterxl.tumblr.com/post/80056718/flex-interview-questions) on his blog. Each question includes an explanation for why you might want to ask it. The only one I'd argue with is the last one, but that's more to do with the fact that he tends to work on more design-centric projects with heavier timeline-based assets than a lot of Flex developers.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Give me the advantages/disadvantages of Raster vs. Vector images within Flex.

A: [Raster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) vs [Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics)